# can lvmcache have split read and write cache?

Tags: lvm, raid, caching

I'm doing some reading on lvmcache-ing, but didn't really find out if you can have split LVs for read and write. Ideally I'd have a nvme based volume for read cache, and a mirror ssd for writeback. Can this be setup?